# Determining subclass out of a lot of subclasses Java

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof, subclass

I have an *interface* `Tree` and an **abstract class** `RBTree` which implements this interface. I also have several classes `Tree1`...`Tree9` which extend this abstract class.

I've written a test unit where i want to do something like this:

```
public void testRandom(RBTree tree){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        rbTree = new Tree1(); //if the tree in the parameter was of instance Tree1
        rbTree = new Tree2(); //if the tree in the parameter was of instance Tree2
        //etc.

        /**
         * do something with rbTree
         */
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this *without* using a chain of if-statements (or a switch) with a lot of `instanceof()` ?

(note: i can't change anything about the design, i know it's not really optimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tree.getClass().newInstance()`.

In case you want to have some more complex logic than instantiation, you would either need the instanceof approach, or better - make each `RBTree` subclass have a method that performs that logic (and make that method abstract in `RBTree`)

Comment: Very easy and simple. Thanks aswell for mentioning the alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rbTree = tree.class.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, you can:

```
string name = tree.getClass().getName()
Class.forName(name).newInstance();
```

Problem is that if the actual implementations have different methods etc. you won't be able to access them.

Comment: why the extra line and going through string?

Comment: In this case it isn't really necessary, but it does provide an alternative to the other answers, which might be handy. I don't know the rest of his code and maybe he likes passing the classname around better than what he's currently doing. It might get hem thinking. That's all.

Comment: classnames should not be passed unless you are going through external systems. The class within the JVM is represented by a Class object